# Client Side parsing of HTTP multi part data in iOS app

Tags: objective-c

I have a multi-part response coming from server(it is asp.net, hosted on IIS) which looks like this:
    "--myboundary\r\n" +
            "Content-Type:image/jpeg\r\n" +
            "Content-Length:" + length.ToString() + "\r\n\r\n";

I want to add the timestamp attribute for the frame (image). how can i add it in the above string and how can I access (extract) the same in my client-side iOS App?

I have tried converting the NSData object to NSString using NSASCIIString encoding but it went futile. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the URL you are looking to parse?

Comment: Can you post the code for sending the response in ASP.NET and parsing the response in Objective-C? How to solve this would depend greatly on how those parts are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to get a string from an HTTP response you use:

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Hi Steven, with the NSUTF8StringEncoding also, i am not able to extract the meaningful string. It is printing some garbage characters.